# when i put border to a div that occupies 100% of the height (height: 100vh) the vertical scroll is shown, how to remove the vertical scroll?

Tags: css

I've had this problem for quite some time and I don't know how to fix it. If I remove the border, the scroll disappears and this is what I want, but if my div has the border, the vertical scroll appears. I would like to keep my div with its respective border. How can I solve that?

```css
div{
 height:100vh;
 background:yellow;
 border:1px solid red;
}
body,html{
  padding:0px;
  margin:0px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Are you using box-sizing:border-box?

Comment: @Paulie_D excuse my ignorance, but I don't use that property. How can that help me solve my problem?

Comment: If you use it the borders will be included in the height calculation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are probably a couple of ways to handle it. By default, `box-sizing` is set to `content-box`. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

So if you have a div that is `100vh` then adding a border will add the width of the top-border plus the width of the bottom-border to the total height. Thus you get a scroll.

You can either set the `div` to `box-sizing: border-box`, like below:

```css
div{
 height: 100vh;
 background:yellow;
 border:1px solid red;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
body,html{
  padding:0px;
  margin:0px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Or, you can account for any spacing of the border or other spacing that affects the overall height by using a `calc` function to subtract the extra height from the total, such as `height: calc(100vh - 2px);`, like below:

```css
div{
 height: calc(100vh - 2px);
 background:yellow;
 border:1px solid red;
}
body,html{
  padding:0px;
  margin:0px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```